# How do I suspress "jf rt search --count" infomational messages?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

When I successfully run a JFrog CLI `jf rt search --count` command, the count is written to stdout while informational messages are written to stderr:

```
$ jf rt search test --count=true --server-id=server_id --recursive=true --include-dirs=true
11:34:23 [Info] Searching artifacts...
11:34:24 [Info] Found 1 artifact.
1
```

How can I suppress the informational messages.  Note that I can't simply redirect stderr to /dev/null as I want error messages when the `jf rt search --count` command fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the log level to Warning, by setting the `JFROG_CLI_LOG_LEVEL` environment variable:

```bash
export JFROG_CLI_LOG_LEVEL=WARN
```

One liner:

```bash
JFROG_CLI_LOG_LEVEL=WARN jf rt search test --count=true --server-id=server_id --recursive=true --include-dirs=true
```

Read more about it under the [Environment Variables](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/environment-variables?tocId=Wrf0qmhAPWtQ7XAWK8%7Ezgw) section in the JFrog CLI documentation.

Comment: Thanks @yahavi.  Setting `JFROG_CLI_LOG_LEVEL=WARN` does what I want, even though `WARN` isn't listed as a possible value for `JFROG_CLI_LOG_LEVEL` in the JFrog [Environment Variables](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/environment-variables?tocId=Wrf0qmhAPWtQ7XAWK8~zgw) documentation.  I suspect (hope) that the documentation is simply missing the `WARN` choice.

Comment: Thanks, @GeoffAlexander. I created this PR to add it: https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/pull/2027.