# How do I suppress "working" messasge from download / upload commands

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

When I run JFrog CLI `jf rt download` and `jf rt upload` commands, I get "working" messages as the download / upload progresses, even when `JFROG_CLI_LOG_LEVEL=WARN` is set:

```
 Working ∙●∙∙∙∙               
 || 25.0KiB/25.0KiB
 || 24.8KiB/24.8KiB
 || 228.0KiB/228.0KiB
 || 300.3KiB/300.3KiB
 || 17.9KiB/17.9KiB
 || 24.0KiB/24.0KiB
 || 76.0KiB/76.0KiB
```

How can I suppress these "working" messages? @yahavi, you answered my previous [JFrog CLI: How do I suspress "jf rt search --count" infomational messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76441821/jfrog-cli-how-do-i-suspress-jf-rt-search-count-infomational-messages) question, so maybe you know the answer to this question as well.

Comment: @yahavi, you answered my previous JFrog CLI: How do I suspress "jf rt search --count" infomational messages? question, so maybe you know the answer to this question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable progress indicators when running a CLI command on a local machine, you can set the CI environment variable to TRUE:

```bash
export CI=TRUE
jf rt download
```

One liner:

```
CI=true jf rt download
```

Comment: Thank @yahavi.  Setting CI=true works like a charm.